# Get rid of a 1 pixel padding/border gap in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, styles

Look at this!
[image: Breaking!]
I really need to get rid of this!
Look at the delcaration!

```
<ListView Name="list" BorderThickness="0">
```

How do I fix it?
This gap doesn't only happen to the scrollbar, it also happens to the items, with or WITHOUT any views.

Comment: The border is probably around the scrollbar; use Snoop to investigate which property should actually be set: http://blois.us/Snoop/

Comment: No no no, the border is also around items! But anyway, I'll try a thing or two with Snoop...

Comment: The comment was mostly in favour of using Snoop; it's invaluable when doing WPF development.

Comment: Doesn't work at all. I select the process, and click the button and nothing happens after 2 minutes or after 100 clicks.

Comment: You open snoop, look select the process, press "Snoop this application" button and a window will pop. Just hover the mouse in your application with Ctrl + Shift pressed and it will select the WPF controls under it and show it on the snoop tree inspector.

Comment: Read my comment again. I am tired of saying the same things multiple times. NOTHING HAPPENS WHEN CLICKING THE BUTTON.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a problem in the `Template`, most likely a property of an internal control which is not bound to any of the properties the ListBox exposes to you.

**Edit by Vercas:** I have found the problem.
This is the template of the `ListView`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListView" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Name="Bd" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Just change the `Padding` of the Border to 0 and you're done.
Here is the result if you don't want to bother finding the property.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListView" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Name="Bd" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Don't forget to add this template to your `ListView`!

Comment: The problem is not in my template, as I eliminated them and the problem persists. How can I fix this if it's not my problem? O_O

Comment: @Vercas: You **cannot** eliminate the template, there is always *some* template.

Comment: Yep, it was in the template. Lemme add it to your answer. Edit: I meant I removed my own template based on the original one.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to fix in Blend if you have it.  if not there is a free trial.  You will have to generate a copy of the control template for the scrollviewer that you are using in that list.  From there you can edit the template for the ScrollBar.

The scroll bars template is going to be several levels of templates deep once you get to it.  ListView Template>ItemsPresenter (In this case a Wrap Panel) Template> ScrollViewer Template > ScrollBar Template.

Comment: The ScrollBar is not the problem, it's the whole ListView! There's a 1 pixel padding in the ListView!